# How do I make a UIScrollView scroll in only one direction?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I already know vertical or horizontal bounces.
What I want is to prevent scrolling up.

So, only the right, left, and bottom directions are scrollable.
How is it possible?

Comment: Where's the code that you've written? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "disable" only top bounce. You can use:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! but if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 is right source code. But I solve it. Thank you guy!!